# Print special PHP Variables

Tags: php, variables, object

I have a object like this

```
stdClass Object
(
    [@promo] => true
    [@rate] => 24.5
    [@baseRate] => 35.0
)
```

How would I print the `@baseRate, @promo, @rate`this variables? When I use `$obj->@promo` this will shows error and same for `$obj['@promo']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the only way to do this is

```
$obj->{"@promo"}
```

Comment: One more thing how can I use in JSON?? I mean obj.{"@promo"} not working

Comment: @Subhojit you mean in JS? Try `obj["@promo"]`